# Quicklook files placed online not local

Tags: ios, objective-c

my app enables the user to look at files that are on the server. so the files (mainly images) aren't local. what is the best way to let the user preview them? does Quicklook support online files previewing? i tried implementing UIDocumentInteractionController and then i figured out that it only works with local files URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I would download the needed images using https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage to cache them.
Once they are local you can use your tool.